# Describe briefly how analogue data differs from digital data.

Tags: data-sets

I was wondering if you could help me to understand the difference between analogue and digital data. I looked it up online but couldn't find a proper answer. If for any reason this is the wrong site for my question please guide me to the correct site, Thank you.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_data, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_signal

Comment: Even just looking up the definitions of "digital" and "analogue" in a dictionary would seem to answer this.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is: analog data is continuous, while digital data is quantized. In other words, a signal that at any point in time might have any real value between 0 and 1 would be considered analog. A signal that at any point in time has a value of either 0 or 1 would be considered digital.